# Reduce text padding inside a Button

Tags: android, button, text, padding

Is ist possible to reduce the text padding inside a normal Android Button a bit, in order to reduce the button´s width?

Of course the whole text should be still visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "normal" Android button varies between themes, but you probably want to define a [custom style](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) for the button that inherits from your button of choice.

Comment: thx  Button button = new Button(context, null, android.R.attr.buttonStyleSmall);  worked

Comment: any solution via XML?

Answer (score 15):

There're `android:minHeight` and `android:minWidth` attribute already set on a button. Make them `0dp` or `1dp` to make the background fit to the text.